# Dynamically change Tab Content of TabHost

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-tabhost, xamarin, mvvmcross

In my case I have several Tabs within TabHost and 1st tab should be able change it's view without navigation from TabHost (to be able to immediately access other tabs).

Is it possible to dynamically change Tab view for TabHost?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, my solution : 
get current tab, and setOnClickListener.

Example:

```
View tab = (View) tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
        tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

cheers :)